# Using if statement with innerHTML to alternate content, my method isn't working... completely

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a javascript function the reads the currnet button's innerHTML and uses an if statement to determine what items to show on screen. On first click it makes the desired changes, but won't do anything on the second click.

```js
function signup() {
  var test = document.getElementById('link-user').innerHTML;

  if (test = 'Sign Up') {
    document.getElementById('signup-name-first').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('signup-name-last').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('signup-email').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('signup-password').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('br1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('br2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('br3').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('btn-sub').innerHTML = 'Sign Up';
    document.getElementById('link-user').innerHTML = 'Existing User';
    document.getElementById('link-forgot').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('signup-name-first').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('signup-name-last').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('signup-email').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('signup-password').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('br1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('br2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('br3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btn-sub').innerHTML = 'Log In';
    document.getElementById('link-user').innerHTML = 'Sign Up';
    document.getElementById('link-forgot').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="win-login" class="win-login eds-win-pop eds-ani-popup">
  <form class="">
    <br />
    <input id="signup-name-first" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="namefirst" class="input-txt eds-input-pop eds-ani-popup" />
    <br id="br1" class="eds-input-pop" />
    <input id="signup-name-last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="namelast" class="input-txt eds-input-pop eds-ani-popup" />
    <br id="br2" class="eds-input-pop" />
    <input id="signup-email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail Address" name="email" class="input-txt eds-input-pop eds-ani-popup" />
    <br id="br3" class="eds-input-pop" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="nameuser" class="input-txt" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="input-txt" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="signup-password" type="password" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" name="passwordconf" class="input-txt eds-input-pop eds-ani-popup" />
    <br />
    <button id="btn-sub" type="submit" class="btn-skyblu" action="">Login</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <a id="link-user" class="link-small" onclick="signup();">New User</a>
  <br />
  <a id="link-forgot" class="link-small" onclick="pwreset();">Forgot Password</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Excuse me mister Chris, could you provide a jsFiddle please?

Comment: Mister, you are using the asignment operator `=` to compare use this `==`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what that is. I'm pretty new to all this.

Edit:
I figured out what jsfiddle is. I'll make one.

Comment: @ChrisTopher: It's nothing you need to worry about. Just provide all relevant code in the question, and others can make off-site demos for themselves if they wish.

Comment: @ChrisTopher Read up on the difference between `=` and `==`. You should know that before attempting something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
if (test = 'Sign Up') {
```

What this says is if you can assign `test` to the value of `'Sign Up'`, run this code inside the if statement.

What you are looking for is the `==` operator, which checks for equal value.

```
if (test == 'Sign Up') {
```

```js
function signup() {
  var test = document.getElementById('link-user').innerHTML;

  if (test == 'Sign Up') {
    document.getElementById('signup-name-first').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('signup-name-last').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('signup-email').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('signup-password').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('br1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('br2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('br3').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('btn-sub').innerHTML = 'Sign Up';
    document.getElementById('link-user').innerHTML = 'Existing User';
    document.getElementById('link-forgot').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('signup-name-first').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('signup-name-last').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('signup-email').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('signup-password').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('br1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('br2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('br3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btn-sub').innerHTML = 'Log In';
    document.getElementById('link-user').innerHTML = 'Sign Up';
    document.getElementById('link-forgot').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="win-login" class="win-login eds-win-pop eds-ani-popup">
  <form class="">
    <br />
    <input id="signup-name-first" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="namefirst" class="input-txt eds-input-pop eds-ani-popup" />
    <br id="br1" class="eds-input-pop" />
    <input id="signup-name-last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="namelast" class="input-txt eds-input-pop eds-ani-popup" />
    <br id="br2" class="eds-input-pop" />
    <input id="signup-email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail Address" name="email" class="input-txt eds-input-pop eds-ani-popup" />
    <br id="br3" class="eds-input-pop" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="nameuser" class="input-txt" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="input-txt" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="signup-password" type="password" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" name="passwordconf" class="input-txt eds-input-pop eds-ani-popup" />
    <br />
    <button id="btn-sub" type="submit" class="btn-skyblu" action="">Login</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <a id="link-user" class="link-small" onclick="signup();">New User</a>
  <br />
  <a id="link-forgot" class="link-small" onclick="pwreset();">Forgot Password</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for the long version! Very informative. Helped the click in my noggin. Now I get the difference between = and ==.

Answer (score 3):

In boolean expressions use `==` not `=`. Like this:

```
 if (test == 'Sign Up') {
    //your code
 }
```

For more informations about comparison operators:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: Such a simple answer! Thank! Works perfectly.